# OpenSSH Windows Error

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I want to connect with putty from one `machine_1` to another Windows machine `machine_2`. So I install a OpenSSH Server on `machine_2`. I generate 2 a key pair with puttygen. I paste the public key in **C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\authorized_keys** [Screenshote Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRobF.png). And here is my `sshd_config`:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.84 2011/05/23 03:30:07 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check     .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none



# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem  sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Subsystem   sftp    C:\OpenSSH\sftp-server.exe
Subsystem   scp /win32openssh/bin/scp.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519*,ssh-rsa*,ssh-dss*,ecdsa-sha2*
```

And when I start PuTTY on `machine_2`and try connect to `machine_2` I got this Error: `Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!`
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMslW.png)
What did I wrong?

Comment: "I generate 2 a key pair with puttygen." in which format did you save private/public keys?

Comment: So I use `SSH-2 RSA`. And I save the private key as `private.ppk` on my desktop and copy it to `machine_2`. I copy the code of the public key out of puttygen and paste it in `authorized_keys`

Comment: The private key should be saved in openssh format

Comment: I think I have the right format. I added a Screenshot of the Key (look at main post)

Comment: It's a public one, and I have told about the private - private.ppk

Comment: then I cant use this file in PuTTY. How is the command for connecting with ssh? I have found out this : `connect Administrator@172.16.17.53` but with wich parameter can I add the key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39061/discussion-between-jofri-and-alex-hha).